# How to upload image in custom option while add the simple product in magento

Tags: magento

I am facing a problem while adding multiple images in custom option at the time of adding a product.

How can I add multiple image in custom option in magento?

Comment: Can you include (edit your post) the code that you have, what error message you get (if any).

Comment: actually i did not get upload image option in custom part of the magento

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default does not offer the ability to upload images for custom options. This functionality must be added through a module or custom programming.